# How to get previous value of <select> in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu

An example.

`red` is selected from the very start.

Then I select `green`. That is, from `red` to `green`.

I can get new value `green` in `event.currentTarget.value`. But how do I get previous `red`?

```
<select className="foo" onChange={this.onSectChange} value="red">
    <option value="no color">No Color</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>  // this one is selected
    <option value="green">Green</option> // this one I will select
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>

onSectChange = (event) => {

    let prevVal = event.??? // How to get a previous value, that is Red
    let newVal = event.currentTarget.value; // Green - is a new value just selected, not previous

}
```

I mean, does React provide this functionality out-of-the-box along with their `SyntheticEvent` creation? Or do I still have to hack to get it?

Answer (score 4):

You can use React's  [controlled components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) to achieve this. The `state` will have the previous value.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
class Select extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      select: 'red',
    }
    this.onSectChange = this.onSectChange.bind(this)
  }
  
  onSectChange(e) {
    var newVal = e.target.value
    console.log(this.state.select, newVal)
    this.setState({
      select: newVal,
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    return <select className="foo" onChange={this.onSectChange} value={this.state.select}>
    <option value="no color">No Color</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>  // this one is selected
    <option value="green">Green</option> // this one I will select
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    </select>  
  }

}
ReactDOM.render(<Select/>, document.getElementById('app'))
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`currentTarget` is a property supported by *browsers* and it doesn't have anything to do with React, in itself.

`SyntheticEvent` is just a wrapper around the browser's native event, which exposes certain browser events.

The closest thing to what you're trying to do that comes to mind is [`Event.originalTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/originalTarget), but it's an experimental feature only implemented in Mozilla.

So, to answer your question: no, React doesn't provide that functionality out of the box. And I wouldn't say you need a *hack* to get the previous value of your dropdown menu.

For instance, you could use `componentWillReceiveProps` and compare `nextProps` with `this.props`.

Please provide more details, if I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use what we call a "controlled" input. [Here's a good explanation of the concept of controlled and uncontrolled inputs.](https://gist.github.com/markerikson/d71cfc81687f11609d2559e8daee10cc)

In your case:

Set your initial state in the constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {dropdownValue: 'red'};
}
```

Set the value of your select input as the value stored in your state

```
<select className="foo" onChange={this.onSectChange} value={this.state.dropdownValue}>
```

Then in your `onChange` event handling function you can get the previous value as it's still stored in state, before overwriting it with the new value from the event

```
onSectChange = (event) => {
    // You haven't yet updated the state, so you still have access to the old value.
    let prevVal = this.state.dropdownValue; 
    let newVal = event.currentTarget.value; 

    // You need to set the new value in your state so the component is
    // rerendered to show the new value as selected
    this.setState({dropdownValue: newVal});
}
```

Answer (score -4):

this is stored in: e.target.defaultValue

Answer (score -4):

use event.target.value will return you the previously value selected