# Creating a dependent dropdown menus in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I want to achieve a dependent dropdown list. So when I choose one item on the first dropdown list, the second dropdown values are reflected and based on second's value the third dropdown values are reflected and so on. Like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhW6x.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any library like [antd](https://ant.design/components/select/) for table and for function
you can see
  [2]: [How to get previous value of <select> in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40085950/how-to-get-previous-value-of-select-in-react). I hope it can help you

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I also needed to maintain the states in the parent for the selected values